# S3 upload user metadata list of String

Tags: java, list, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, metadata

I am currently working on S3 upload in Java, and I am to add a set of user metadata to the file. I am trying to understand, if I can add a list of string to one of the parameters in the user metadata.

My current code snippet is the below -

```
ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();

Map<String, Object> userMetadata = new HashMap<String, Object>();

userMetadata.put("a", "a1");
userMetadata.put("b", "b1");

List<String> c = new ArrayList<String>();
c.add("c1");
c.add("c2");
userMetadata.put("c", c);

objectMetadata.setUserMetadata(userMetadata);
```

However, I am getting a compile time error at the line "*objectMetadata.setUserMetadata(userMetadata);*"

Comment: What compile time error are you getting? According to the [JavaDoc I found](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ObjectMetadata.html#setUserMetadata-java.util.Map-) the Method expects a `Map<String, String>` and not a `Map<String, Object>` like you are trying to pass

Answer (score 0):

[`setUserMetadata`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ObjectMetadata.html#setUserMetadata-java.util.Map-) takes a `Map<String, String>`, not a `Map<String, Object>` like you have - so you can't use a list directly there. You could, for example, join it:

```
Map<String, String> userMetadata = new HashMap<>(); // Note the type!

userMetadata.put("a", "a1");
userMetadata.put("b", "b1");

List<String> c = new ArrayList<>();
c.add("c1");
c.add("c2");
userMetadata.put("c", String.join(",", c); // list is joined when added to the map

objectMetadata.setUserMetadata(userMetadata);
```